# How to combine text field and graphic element in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have requirement to show data in table column in a way to graphically represent severity of value. Meaning, depending on data value in range 1-10, I should show different color circle together with value, as shown on image.

[image]

Any idea what is the best way how to do this in jasper report template. Not sure if  it is possible to use ellipse graphic element for this.

Thanks

Comment: You can use expression for *image* element to show different images, for example

Comment: Another option is to use "Widgets Pro" elements

Comment: Using *image* with different *forecolor* or/and *background* colors (set with help of *net.sf.jasperreports.style.backcolor* or *net.sf.jasperreports.style.forecolor* properties) is another way